# how to release object of GMSPolygon in GMSMapView?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, gmsmapview

I am working with `GMSMapView`, in which i need to draw around 2k `GMSPolygon` at a time.

App memory increases drastically as soon as this drawing process starts.

All this polygons are stored into an array so we can clear those polygons individually,

By using following method we are clearing all polygons,

```
for polygon in self.polygonArray {
    polygon.map = nil
} 
self.polygonArray.removeAll()
```

But even after clearing all polygons app memory is not decreasing.

Is there any other way to clear all polygons?

Thanks.